# A question on identifying normal subgroups of $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $H=\{e,(1 2)(3 4)\}$ and $K=\{e,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ be subgroups of $S_4$, where $e$ denotes the identity element of $S_4$. Which of the following are correct?

1. $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $S_4$.
2. $H$ is normal in $K$ and $K$ is normal in $A_4$.
3. $H$ is normal in $A_4$ but not normal in $S_4$.
4. $K$ is normal in $S_4$ but $H$ is not.

   I know the condition for a subgroup $H$ to be normal in $G$ but that includes too much computation as $S_4$ has $24$ elements in all. I have studied the group of symmetries of square i.e. $D_4$ and its geometrical interpretation and I think that might be a clue to solve such type of problem relatively easy. Kindly correct me if I am wrong and provide any possible short method to do this.

Comment: yes..1 is not correct.

Comment: You should've made it clear what you are asking. When you write up claims, people, at least myself, think you are asking us to prove all those claims. I edited your post.

Comment: It's a MCQ, of CSIR-NET-JRF, so basically what OP is asking which of the options are true and which are not and why.

Comment: @KushalBhuyan Check out the edit history, it wasn't clear that the question was asking for that.

Comment: @Emre..read in OP, "I have studied the group of symmetries of square i.e. $D_4$ and its geometrical interpretation and I think that might be a clue to solve such type of problem relatively easy".

Answer (score 1):

$H$ is not normal subgroup of $S_4$. For example, you can check that $(23)(12)(34)(23) = (13)(24) \not\in H$.

$K$ is normal subgroup of $S_4$, and it named as Klein subgroup of $S_4$. To prove that $K$ is normal subgroup, you can:

- Check it directly (taking $\sigma \in S_4$, compute $\sigma \alpha \sigma^{-1}$ with $\alpha \in K$)
- Or, you can see that the conjugation in $S_n$ doesn't change the cycle structure, it follows that this subgroup is a union of conjugacy classes, and therefore is normal.

By the reason, you can see that $K$ is normal group in $A_4$.

EDIT: As @Kushal Bhuyan comment, $H$ is normal in $K$ but not in $A_4$.

Comment: Do you really mean that your $\alpha$ belong to $S_4$?

Comment: Thanks, it is my mistake :)

Comment: @GAVD..thanks for your answer but I needed to identify these using symmetries of a square as stated in OP.

Comment: $H$ is normal in $K$

Answer (score 1):

While there are 24 permutations in $S_4$ we can break the  into a few varieties.

If H or K are normal for the simple transpositions. i.e. (1,2)  They will  be normal for all of $S_4,$  since every element of $S_4$ is composed of transpositions.

$A_4$ has two basic varieties of elements, the disjoint transpositions and the 3-cycles e.g. (1,2,3)

Answer (score 0):

GAVD correct answer, but $H$ is normal in $K$.

(1) and (3) are false.